# Erro no JDBC do Postgres no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql

Estou tentando fazer um projeto pra testar a conexão no banco de dados PostgreSQL (Estou utilizando a versão 9.2) no Eclipse (Versão Mars). Estou utilizando o postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc3 e adicionando o mesmo na Build Path. Só que, ao tentar executar a classe pra testar a conexão, aparece uma mensagem de match e pede pra escolher uma classe que está no pacote do JDBC e a classe de teste. Ao tentar executar a classe de teste, diz a que a tentativa de conexão falhou. Como devo proceder?

Comment: Considere incluir o código que está usando para realizar a conexão

Comment: Considere postar a stacktrace do erro também, vai facilitar para podermos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Inclua a classe de conexão e o stacktrace aqui.

Comment: Adicione a stacktrace do erro, além da estrutura do seu projeto.